# allure - API tests are shown separately instead of history

Tags: postman, allure, newman

I am generating API automation results with newman with following command

```
newman run tests.collection.json -e tests.postman_environment.json --folder "Auth" --reporters allure --reporter-allure-export ./allure-results
```

Followed by following commands to generate history and reports as per [Documentation](https://allurereport.org/docs/history-and-retries/)

```
[For first run]
allure generate --clean && allure open

[For next runs]
newman run ...
cp -r allure-report/history/ allure-results
allure generate --clean && allure open
```

But the reports get generated as two separate tests instead of storing previous result in  History.

Am I missing any step?

[image: Generated report]